# Text to Column (Date) using current year instead of the timestamp

Tags: excel, vba, text-to-column

I'm using text to columns as part of a VBA macro to separate timestamps into 2 other columns. When I format Column B to dd/mm/yyyy it uses the current year 2020 instead of 2019. Is there a way to adjust my macro to pull the year from the original timestamp or alternatively, pull the year from Column C once Text to Columns has completed?

[image: Reference1]

[image: Reference2]

```
Range("A5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A5"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 3), Array(2, 3), Array(3, 3)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("B5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B5"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 8), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: You are splitting the string on the comma. I do not thing Text-to-columns is the best tool here.  Parsing the string to create a date that Excel will recognize is a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses arrays:

```
Sub mydatesplit()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = .Range("A5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value

        Dim outArr() As Variant
        ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To 3)

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            Dim spltStr() As String
            spltStr = Split(Replace(arr(i, 1), ",", ""), " ")
            If UBound(spltStr) >= 5 Then
                outArr(i, 1) = spltStr(0)
                outArr(i, 2) = DateValue(spltStr(2) & " " & spltStr(1) & " " & spltStr(3))
                outArr(i, 3) = TimeValue(spltStr(4) & " " & spltStr(5))
            End If
        Next i

        .Range("B5").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), UBound(outArr, 2)).Value = outArr
    End With
End Sub
```

After Running:

[image]

---

BTW with Dynamic Array formulas newly introduced into Excel with the latest subscription one can use fairly simple formula:

Date:

```
=--TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A5,",","")," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($1:$7)-1)*999+1,999)),{3,2,4}))
```

Time

```
=--TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A5,",","")," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($1:$7)-1)*999+1,999)),{5,6}))
```

Comment: The array formula works pretty well, thank you! I just need help adjusting it please. So what i need left over in A Column is the Day only, B Column is the date (MM/DD/YEAR) and C Column YEAR, Time (plus PM, EST).

Comment: Formulas will not replace the value to which they reference, they will need to be in different columns than the original data.  As far as the vba,  Just replace the `.Range("B5")` with `.Range("A5")` and the Third output line should be: `outArr(i, 3) = TimeValue(spltStr(3) & " " & spltStr(4) & " " & spltStr(5))`

Comment: I'm getting an error with the change of the third output, any ideas?
`If UBound(spltStr) >= 5 Then
                outArr(i, 1) = spltStr(0)
                outArr(i, 2) = DateValue(spltStr(2) & " " & spltStr(1) & " " & spltStr(3))
                outArr(i, 3) = TimeValue(spltStr(3) & " " & spltStr(4) & " " & spltStr(5))
            End If
        Next i

        .Range("A5").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), UBound(outArr, 2)).Value = outArr`

Comment: Sorry: `outArr(i, 3) = spltStr(3) & " " & spltStr(4) & " " & spltStr(5)`